# Hosted Blazor WebAssembly with Admin Pages

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application that is being hosted by an ASP.NET Core backend. In addition to serving the Blazor application, the backend also has a few API endpoints used within the Blazor application along with some pages that serve as an admin dashboard.

During local development, all was working correctly and I could navigate from inside the Blazor application to an admin page and back again. Once I published this setup to a development server the Blazor app seems to be blocking any requests to the admin pages. I know this is possible as that is what the built-in identity system does. Whenever I try to access my `/admin` page the Blazor application stays open and shows the message: **Sorry, there's nothing at this address.**

What do I need to adjust to have things operate as they do locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I discovered that my problem is because of how the `service-worker.published.js` handles requests. I have this application setup using the PWA feature for better offline support.

For more information on this subject check out the documentation Microsoft provides here: [Support server-rendered pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#support-server-rendered-pages)